# Model method call from controller with and without self

Tags: model, controller, ruby-on-rails-5, self

I have 2 methods in my model. The functions of both are same, but how to simplify it as one method. I have to call this model method from controller. In one Iam calling based on the id, one without id.
This is my controller method call to model

```
def get_mages
  @url = MyTable.find(params[:id])
  if @url
    render partial: "home/my_partial", locals: {:images => @url.images, :site_url => @url.site_url}
  else
      @url = params[:site_url]
      render partial: "home/my_partial", locals: {:images => MyTable.live_images(@url), :site_url => @url}
  end
end
```

And this is my model function

```
class MyTable < ActiveRecord::Base
    def images
      images = []
      agent = Mechanize.new
      page = agent.get(site_url)
        page.images.each do |image|
                images << {url: image}
        end    
      images
    end
    
    def self.live_images(site_url)
      images = []
      agent = Mechanize.new
      page = agent.get(site_url)
        page.images.each do |image|
                images << {url: image}
        end    
      images
    end
end
```

Any way to make both of the model methods(images, and self.live_images(site_url)) as one.
Any help is appreciatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the class method from the instance method and avoid repetition:

```
class MyTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  def images
    self.class.live_images(site_url)
  end
  
  def self.live_images(site_url)
    Mechanize.new.get(site_url).images.map do |image|
      {url: image}
    end    
  end
end
```

And in the controller just condition the url and images depending whether the MyTable record exists or not:

```
def get_mages
  table = MyTable.find(params[:id])
  @url = params[:site_url]
  @url = table.site_url if table.present?
  images = if table.present?
             table.images
           else
             MyTable.live_images(@url)
           end

  render partial: "home/my_partial", locals: { images: images, site_url: @url }
end
```